# How to crawl in desired order or Synchronously in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

## **The problem**

I'm trying to create a spider that crawls and scrapes every product from a  store and outputs the results to a JSON file, that includes going into each category in the main page and scraping every product (just name and price), each product class page includes infinite scrolling.

My problem is that each time I make a request after scraping the first page of a class of item, instead of getting the next batch of items from that same type, I get the items from the next category and the output ends up being a mess.

## **What I've already tried**

I've already tried messing with settings and forcing concurrent requests to one and setting different priorities for each request.

I've found out about asynchronous crawling but I can't figure out how to create the requests in order.

## **Code**

```
import scrapy
from scrapper_pccom.items import ScrapperPccomItem

class PccomSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pccom'
    allowed_domains = ['pccomponentes.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.pccomponentes.com/componentes']

    #Scrapes links for every category from main page
    def parse(self, response):
        categories = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"enlace-secundario")]/@href')
        prio = 20
        for category in categories:
            url = response.urljoin(category.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_item_list, priority=prio, cb_kwargs={'prio': prio})
            prio = prio - 1

    #Scrapes products from every page of each category      
    def parse_item_list(self, response, prio):

        products = response.xpath('//article[contains(@class,"tarjeta-articulo")]')
        for product in products:
            item = ScrapperPccomItem()
            item['name'] = product.xpath('@data-name').extract()
            item['price'] = product.xpath('@data-price').extract()
            yield item

        #URL of the next page
        next_page = response.xpath('//div[@id="pager"]//li[contains(@class,"c-paginator__next")]//a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            next_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_url, self.parse_item_list, priority=prio, cb_kwargs={'prio': prio})
```

## **Output vs Expected**

What it does: Category 1 page 1 > Cat 2 page 1 > Cat 3 page 1 > ...

What I want it to do: Cat 1 page 1 > Cat 1 page 2 > Cat 1 page 3 > ... > Cat 2 page 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy,

Get list of all categories in `all_categories`, now don't scrape all links, just scrape 1st category link, and once all pages have been scraped for that category, then send request to another category link.

Here is the code, I did not run code so there maybe some syntax error, but logic is what you need

```
class PccomSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pccom'
    allowed_domains = ['pccomponentes.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.pccomponentes.com/componentes']

    all_categories = []

    def yield_category(self):
        if self.all_categories:
            url = self.all_categories.pop()
            print("Scraping category %s " % (url))
            return scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_item_list)
        else:
            print("all done")


    #Scrapes links for every category from main page
    def parse(self, response):
        categories = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"enlace-secundario")]/@href')

        self.all_categories = list(response.urljoin(category.extract()) for category in categories)
        yield self.yield_category()


    #Scrapes products from every page of each category      
    def parse_item_list(self, response, prio):

        products = response.xpath('//article[contains(@class,"tarjeta-articulo")]')
        for product in products:
            item = ScrapperPccomItem()
            item['name'] = product.xpath('@data-name').extract()
            item['price'] = product.xpath('@data-price').extract()
            yield item

        #URL of the next page
        next_page = response.xpath('//div[@id="pager"]//li[contains(@class,"c-paginator__next")]//a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            next_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_url, self.parse_item_list)

        else:
            print("All pages of this category scraped, now scraping next category")
            yield self.yield_category()
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you so much ! Worked perfectly !